# WebApi - passing streamContent back to the Client getting error 500

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following error and am not sure where to fix it. 
Code compiles, and runs, but i get a 500 back which means something is up in the server code.  I found this while debugging....thoughts?

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

**strong text**

```
 public async void ExportData()
{
  //code to request data from the server
 requestUri = ipaddress:port/api/data/export?dataFileId={Id};
 var response = await Client.GetAsync(requestUri);

}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]    
[Route("export")] 
public HttpResponseMessage Export
var fileContents = _dataService.ExportDataFiles(dataFileId);
                var fileLines = string.Empty;
                //  fileContents.Lines.Aggregate(fileLines, (s, s1) => s+=s1 + Environment.NewLine);
                using (var multipartContent = new MultipartContent())
                {
                    foreach (var fileContent in fileContents)
                    {
                        foreach (var fileLine in fileContent.Lines)
                        {
                            fileLines += fileLine + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                        var fileStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileLines));
                        var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                        streamContent.Headers.ContentType =
                                       System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(
                                          "multipart/related; boundary=cbsms-main-boundary"); 

                        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                         {

                             FileName = fileContent.Name
                         };

                        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/data");

                        multipartContent.Add(streamContent);                        
                    }

                      var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                       response.Content = multipartContent;

                    return response;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good answer on how to best send the items back or how to deal with that conflict, so i decided to use WebApi 2 IHttpActionResult.   It is an excellent use case and SUCCESS!!!
I abstracted the creation of the HttResponseMessage and sent the entire set of data in Json over to the client.  I verified this with Postman and Fiddler, then was able to break out the Json without parsing directly, but using casting.
Check this out!

Decreased the number of lines in my code on the Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("export")]
    public IHttpActionResult ExportActionResult(Guid dataFileSetId)
    {
        var fileContents = _dataService.ExportParameterFiles(dataFileSetId);

         return Ok(fileContents);          

    }
```

From the client:

```
 public async void ExportData()
{
   //code to request data from the server
   requestUri = ipaddress:port/api/data/export?dataFileId={Id};
   var response = await Client.GetAsync(requestUri);

  var result = responseTask;
        if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readTask = 
                result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<DataFlatFileDto>>();
            readTask.Wait();
}
```

Now read task contains the files I sent from the server, and they are cast into the DataFileDto, so the name and data portions are set and data is ready for use in the client!

This article was key in laying out how to consume the IHttpActionResult:
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consuming-web-api-in-dotnet-using-httpclient